# Pandas dataframe fill with mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,1,1,4,4,3, 1, 3], 'name':['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name1', 'name2', 'name1', 'name1', 'name3', 'name3', 'name2', 'name2']})
```

```
id   name
1  name1
2  name2
3  name2
4  name1
1  name2
1  name1
4  name1
4  name3
3  name3
1  name2
3  name2
```

And I want to fill all the names with the mode of the id of the row (if there are more than one element that are mode, fill with anyone), the final dataframe would look like this:

```
id   name
1  name1
2  name2
3  name2
4  name1
1  name1
1  name1
4  name1
4  name1
3  name2
1  name1
3  name2
```

I thought on groupby id and get the mode and then merge the dataframes by I can't seem to find the mode aggregating function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `groupby().transform()`:

```
df['mode'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
    id   name   mode
0    1  name1  name1
1    2  name2  name2
2    3  name2  name2
3    4  name1  name1
4    1  name2  name1
5    1  name1  name1
6    4  name1  name1
7    4  name3  name1
8    3  name3  name2
9    1  name2  name1
10   3  name2  name2
```

Comment: Great exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Is iat[0] faster than just [0]? Or there isn't much of a difference?